# Using a custom domain name... but which one is my DNS?

Tags: dns, hosting

I hosted my app on a service called Modulus.io, and I bought a domain name from Gandi.net. I understand the next steps are to point them to each other, but there is one step I'm confused about. I need to point my Gandi.net profile to Modulus.io's DNS, but which one is its DNS? My existing url at modulus is (http://jamscope-21300.onmodulus.net/), is that the DNS? Or is it asking for something more general to modulus?

Like this page http://wiki.gandi.net/en/dns/change I followed the instructions and put http://jamscope-21300.onmodulus.net/ inside the DNS1 box, but I dont know if that's the DNS its asking for. Also, it says it will take 6 hours to a day to actually work, so I have no way of knowing whether I'm waiting for it to work or it's not working at all. Please let me know!

Answer (score 3):

Today I had the same problem and the solution is quiet easy. I have Gandi.net and modulus.io as well.

```
Steps to do on modulus:
-> Open your project
-> Administration
-> Custom Domains
-> Insert your domain in there (e.x. jamscope.com)
-> Save

Steps to do on Gandi.net
-> Open your domain
-> Zone files -> Edit the zone
-> Create new version
-> Add the public IP-Adresses of modulus.io 
-> I hosted on amazon so my new entries are:
   First:   Type A, Name @, Value 107.21.216.112
   Second:  Type A, Name @, Value 54.236.216.66
-> Activate your newly created zone file
```

Public addresses of modulus can be found here: [Click](https://modulus.io/codex/projects/domains)

Take care that these changes take some hours to take affect but they worked for me, that the page is available with your new domain. All these steps are decribed [here](https://modulus.io/codex/projects/domains) too.

Comment: Hi, I dont get the amazon bit, i thought it involves only Gandi and Modulus?

Comment: See here: http://help.modulus.io/customer/portal/articles/1700863-custom-domains

Modulus has load balancers in different regions and providers. One of those is Amazon, and so that's the one chaosbohne chose

Comment: what do u write for TTL?